# StringBuilder vs Span<string> in C#

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between `StringBuilder` and `Span<string>` in **C#**?

Is the same code used in `StringBuilder` as in `Span<string>`?

If yes, then what is the difference between them, and if not, *which one is better*?

Comment: A `Span<string>` is a pointer to a buffer which contains strings. It's similar to a `string[]`. Ask yourself, is there a difference between a `StringBuilder` and a `string[]`?

Comment: I'm sure he meant `Span<char>`, I didn't even correct him lol

Comment: Yeah, the same still applies. A `Span<char>` is a pointer to a buffer which contains chars. It's similar to a `char`. Ask yourself, is there a difference between a `StringBuilder` and a `char[]`? A `StringBuilder` is conceptually a wrapper over a `char[]`, which expands it as necessary, and adds useful methods like `Append` and `AppendFormat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different.
Each `string` is an `array` of characters. In the definition of a normal `string`, an `array` is defined and if you want to make any other changes, another `array` is defined and as a result, **another memory is allocated**, but the `StringBuilder` comes and creates a final array. This explanation was very simple and concise and without details, [which is complete here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?msclkid=a0cd344cb4f111ecb46cf8fccaad39&view=net-6.0)

In the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,adf60ee46ebd299f) of `StringBuilder`, you can also see that it is using the same common types and don't work on the structure.

**`Span` is a `ref struct`** that is a completely different type and that is why it is not used everywhere.

Of course, `Span` is not only used for `string`. It can be done for any other **immutable type**. [FMI](https://nishanc.medium.com/an-introduction-to-writing-high-performance-c-using-span-t-struct-b859862a84e4)

Answer (score 8):

`StringBuilder` grows to any size as you insert characters, while `Span<>` only ever points to a pre-allocated, fixed buffer. It will never grow.

The other two questions are just nonsense.

Edit: I will point out that there is an internal [`ValueStringBuilder`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Common/src/System/Text/ValueStringBuilder.cs) that works on a span (and thus has a fixed maximum size), but is much more efficient within its limitations.

Comment: "StringBuilder grows to any size as you insert characters, while Span<> only ever points to a pre-allocated, fixed buffer" what means 'buffer' ?

Comment: Buffer is the common nomenclature for a general-purpose allocated chunk of memory. In this particular instance, I'm talking about native memory allocated using `stackallock` and stored as a span to be used in the `ValueStringBuilder`.